# Whats the correct decoding of this regex: ^(\\s*\\[abc.*?)(\\])

Tags: java, regex

Here is the regex I'm looking at. I I've breaken it down into parts & am trying to understand what the below means .

```
^(\\s*\\[abc.*?)(\\])
```

This regex:

```
^- start of line
\\ --> matches \
s* --> matches character s ( 0 to unlimited times)
\\--> matches \

[abc.*?)(\\] --- I'm not sure what does this match exactly?
```

Comment: Did you try going through some regex tutorial? You'll find `\\s` combinedly matches whitespace.

Comment: yeah I went through tutorial. Also tried regex101. It says the same there

Answer (score 1):

Double `\\` mess is for Java. Remove one from there and try again explaining.

```
^(\s*\[abc.*?)(\])
```

Now the explanation again:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    abc                      'abc'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\\s*\\[abc.*?)(\\])
```

is a regular expression that is escaped for use in a Java string. After unescaping (after it's [compiled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) by the [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)), it's

```
^(\s*\[abc.*?)(\])
```

Each piece:

```
^
```

is a [`^`:start of line/input anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/578411)

```
(
```

is the start of a [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127)

```
\s*
```

is [`*`:zero or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) [`\s`:whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067350)

```
\[abc
```

is the literal string `[abc`. The open-square-bracket is literal because it's [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078). Were it not escaped, it would be a special character indicating the start of a [character class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553171).

```
.*?
```

is a [*reluctantly* zero or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) of any character

```
)
```

is the end of the capture group

```
(\])
```

is another capture group with a single literal close-square-bracket (literal because it's escaped).

---

All links in this answer are from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496).

Answer (score 0):

Pictorial representation from [debuggex beta](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CD9m1DxUrAqIbff2)

[image]