# What does the whitespace in Python RegEx '^(.+?(\d*)) *$' mean?

Tags: python, regex

What does the whitespace in Python RegEx `^(.+?(\d*)) *$`  mean?

> pat = re.compile('^(.+?(\d*)) *$',re.M)

Does `*` mean `\s*`?

Can the whitespace  be ignored? i.e. is `^(.+?(\d*)) *$` same as `^(.+?(\d*))*$`?

I ran some examples, and it seems that the answers to the above two questions are no.

Thanks!

Comment: The space is a space, `\s` includes space, newlines, tabs and much more depending on the language.

Comment: No, ` *` is any number of space characters. `\s` matches more whitespace than just ` `.

Comment: but can white space be used without using `\\` in front for escaping?

Comment: @Tim You don't need to escape a space. Basically what you have is "repeat the space zero or more times". Where space is `0x20`. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291474/how-to-choose-between-whitespace-pattern/21067350#21067350) about `\s`, it depends on the language what it matches exactly.

Comment: @Tim: White space doesn't need to be escaped. If it helps you read the regex more clearly, you can use `[ ]` instead of just a space.

Comment: Note that if you use verbose mode (which I highly recommend), whitespace that you don't want the regex engine to ignore *does* need escaping, either with a backslash or by putting it in a character class.

Comment: The `\s*` is much clearer and almost certainly less buggy, than naked ' ', if that is intended why not use [ ]* so the reader is sure it's deliberate.  If you are looking for trailing spaces, generaly tabs ought to count to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this out for yourself on an online regex tool such as http://www.regex101.com

It's just a space character.

For your info, `\s` is actually 'whitespace', so it matches tabs, form feeds and other characters as well as spaces [Whitespace link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067350)

Comment: That site's nice!  It confirms my suspicion on "12345 "

Answer (score 3):

`*` means 0 or more occurances, `$` anchors the match to the end of line, so it's allowing (probably) trailing spaces, but not tabs, unless it's actually a tab.

No if you remove that white space, lines with invisible spaces after them won't match.

As it stands it's matching a line sequence of one or more non-digits, followed by optional digits and optional spaces.

Actually if debugging I'd have to look up what happens on a line like "12345 " with the non-greedy matching as I'd tend to write myself something like "^(\D+(\d+))\s*$" or "^(\D*.(\d+))\s*$" depending on intention.  In old days you had to code against the greedy matching yourself, which means I generally avoid stuff like .+(\d*) through habit.  Capturing 0 digits generally is a bug, as is having first digit consumed by .+