# Difference between using '\s' and an actual space in regex?

Tags: regex

I have the string `id=0515 abcdefghijk`. With the goal of matching only the `0515`, I created the following regex: `((?<=id=).*(?<=\s))`.

My result was `0515` (with the space between the id and letters included).

If I change my regex to the following (replace the '\s' with an actual space), I get my intended result of just the numbers with no space at the end:  `((?<=id=).*(?= ))`

Is it okay to use an actual space instead of the character code? Or does my regex need more work?

Comment: Yes, for your case a space works. `\s` matches any whitespace [character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067350/6622817) (spaces, tabs, carriage returns, new lines...)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The difference is that  specifically matches a space, while `\s` will match any whitespace character (`\r`, `\n`, `\t`, `\f` and `\v`).

While there's nothing wrong with using a space in a regex, considering you're only looking for the digits, why not simply use `\d` (which matches any digit, `0` to `9`)?

This will cut down your regex signifcantly, and achieve the same result, as can be seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/T82UfW/1/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I now understand the differences, makes sense. Also not all the time will id have all numbers, otherwise using `/d` indeed would be a simpler approach.  Thank you.