# Python replace with backslash

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a string and I would like to add a `\` before some characters.

I have my string in terms_string and what I do is:

```
charmap = {':', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '<', '>', '/', '\\', '='}
for key in charmap:
    terms_string = terms_string.replace(key, '\\'+key)
```

Everything works fine but I get a `\\` instead a `\`.

For example for the charmap I get

```
{'(', ')', '/', ':', '<', '=', '>', '[', '\\', ']', '{', '}'}
```

insted

```
{'(', ')', '/', ':', '<', '=', '>', '[', '\', ']', '{', '}'}
```

This only happens with the character \, not with the others.

Any idea why this is happening? Python configuration maybe? Thanks!

Comment: You can go check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice . Your answer is here :)

Comment: If I do print(terms_string) I get everything with double \, so I think there is a problem.

Comment: What do you want to achieve when trying to replace \\? You want to replace a single \ with \\ or you want to replace \\ with \\\ ?

Comment: The **representation** as returned by `repr()`, in the console or in a sequence structure shows the escape sequence with two backslashes. But that is actually only one. If you print the singular string it will show it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your goal when replacing \ but these options may work for you.

```
terms_string = "foo (bar fo/o: b\a=r)"
charmap = {':', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', '<', '>', '/', '\\', '='}
for key in charmap:
    terms_string = terms_string.replace(key, "\\{}".format(key))
print(terms_string)
>>> foo \(bar fo\/o\: b\=r\)
```

or

```
import re
terms_string = "foo (bar fo/o: b\a=r)"
result = re.sub(r"([:\(\)\{\}<>/\\=])", r"\\\1", terms_string)
print(result)
>>> foo \(bar fo\/o\: b\=r\)
```

Also consider `re.escape`

```
terms_string = "foo (bar fo/o: b\a=r)"
print(re.escape(terms_string))
>>> foo\ \(bar\ fo/o:\ b=r\)
```

Comment: I want to add \ before special characters because after that I want to use that string as a regular expression. I really liked re.escape, but before the spaces it adds a \ instead substitute the space by \s and I think that could be a problem

Comment: if you want to use those strings in regular expressions, then `re.escape()` is actually what you need to use. I didn't understand the last part of your comment thou

Comment: Normally what I always do in regex is \s for a space. Isn't that the normal thing to do?

Comment: I am not extremely sure, but maybe `\s` is useful mainly when you want to capture multiple spaces with something like `\s+` ?

Comment: Here they explain it very well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763198/difference-between-using-s-and-an-actual-space-in-regex). \s works for any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, newlines...). So I guess in this case a simple space would work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, you're definitely right!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because \ is an escape character. If you give a single \ it looks for the character next to it to understand what this means. So for a literal \ it puts a \\ which does not then escape the \. Escape characters are characters with special meanings. For example '\n' means new line. Not a literal \n. Hope this clarifies your doubt. This happens not just in python but most languages.

Further [reading](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/3-comments-literals/)

Comment: So how would I get what I want? I think I am doing it right but somehow there is some problem with my python.

Comment: What do you want to do with the single \\

Comment: I want to get only one \, but I get two.